# Make a smooth scroll effect

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, smoothing

I'm looking for make this smooth scroll effect :

http://onirim.com/about-us/

How I can do ? I didn't find something about that.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel

Comment: mousewheel function may be useful to you. Check the link above

Comment: [Please](http://marketblog.envato.com/web-design/scroll-hijacking/)
[don't](http://trentwalton.com/2013/10/23/scroll-hijacking/)
[hijack](http://www.creativebloq.com/netmag/dangers-scroll-hijacking-web-design-81412684)
[my](http://creativecoon.com/why-using-parallax-and-smooth-scrolling-on-pages-is-a-bad-idea/)
[scrollbar](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/47n9ph/psa_dont_use_smooth_scroll_scriptsplugins_on_your/)

Comment: Anthony Astige : It's not the question...